# How can I solve the following differential equation by reducing it to first order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation

$ \displaystyle y''+ \left( 1+ \frac{1}{y} \right)y'^{2} =0 \tag*{} $

The book in which I found this question says that It can be solved by reducing it to a first order differential equation but I can't seem to find a way to do so.

Comment: Hint: divide by $y'$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\displaystyle y''+ \left( 1+ \frac{1}{y} \right)y'^{2} =0 $$
Divie by $y'$ then:
$$\dfrac {y''}{y'}+  y'+ \dfrac{y'}{y}  =0 $$
$$(\ln y')'+(\ln y)' +y'=0$$
$$(\ln y'+\ln y +y)'=0$$

Integrate.

Answer (score 2):

Switching variables, the equation write
$$-\frac {x''}{[x']^3}+ \left( 1+ \frac{1}{y} \right)\frac 1{[x']^2}=0$$ and assuming $x'\neq 0$
$$x''-\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right) x'=0$$ Now, let $p=x'$ and you face a very simple equation.
$$p=C\, y\, e^y$$